# Is if_freenameindex supported on android?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I was trying to port some of my C++ code to Android and while compiling I got many errors related to this one:

error: 'if_freenameindex' was not declared in this scope

Looking for the problem I found this: https://plus.google.com/+ElliottHughes/posts/7NZqaFxyk98

which seems to imply that that function is indeed supported.

What am I missing?

Other relevant info:
In the application.mk I used APP_STL := gnustl_shared

I am pretty new to the android world so let me know what kind of information you need to help me solve this problem.

Comment: I wonder if the fact that under arch-arm/usr/include/net/if.h, the file linux/if.h is included, but only two functions from that include are declared as extern may mean that only those these two are currently supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started looking in the platform includes and it looks like a set of functions I need is not present. I guess I'll have to find a workaround.